# Add draggable marker to flutter app mapbox

Tags: flutter, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I am building a flutter app using the **mapbox_maps_flutter: 0.4.4** package. There is no official flutter documentation so I am just using the examples and the android api to figure things out.
But what i am trying to achieve is have a custom marker icon on my map that is initially in the same position as the user's current location, and then anytime I drag scroll on the map, the marker moves (by taking the center point of the camera).
If this is too complex, then I would just like the marker to be draggable (like the uber app when you're requesting a trip).

I don't mind being pointed to some flutter documentation or at least a good and detailed example on how to use markers.

Lastly, please e aware that I am using version **0.44** which is no longer compatible with mapbox_gl I believe.

Here's some relevant code:

```
MapboxMap? mapboxMap;

_onMapCreated(MapboxMap mapboxMap) async {
    this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
    mapboxMap.location
        .updateSettings(LocationComponentSettings(enabled: true)); // show current position
    mapboxMap.scaleBar.updateSettings(ScaleBarSettings(
      enabled: false,)); // hide the scale bar
    mapboxMap.compass.updateSettings(CompassSettings(
      enabled: false,)); // hide the compass
  }

Widget _map() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8, //mapbox needs to have a height
      child: MapWidget(
          resourceOptions: ResourceOptions(accessToken: MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN),
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        key: const ValueKey("mapWidget"),
        cameraOptions: CameraOptions(
            center: Point(
                coordinates: Position(
                  widget.location.longitude,
                  widget.location.latitude,
                )).toJson(),
            zoom: 17.5
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is there any specific use case you should be using this particular library? If not, you can follow this documentation about Google Maps in Flutter: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-maps-in-flutter?hl=pt-br#0

If this helps you let me know, I'll put it as an answer so you can upvote.

Comment: Is it possible to listen to map scrolls with this package? If so, you could simply try getting user's location, setting it as the initial map location, presenting a marker on top of it (even with `Stack`), in the center, and then listening to the map scroll changes and assuming that the map's scroll is where the marker is.

Comment: @franciscogomes google maps is just way more expensive for my use case. But thanks for the reference

Comment: @Genix that's a good makeshift solution and i will try it if I cannot find the exact way to do what I want using the package alone. If i try your solution and it works, I will notify you to make it the official answer

Comment: you can use the Symbol class from the mapbox_gl package in Flutter. check out this https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_gl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. As I said before, the mapbox_maps_flutter: 0.4.4 is AS OF THIS MOMENT not compatible with mapbox_gl. The way to add custom_markers is to use point annotations in conjunction with the annotation manager.

Here's what the setup looks like:

```
    MapboxMap? mapboxMap;
    PointAnnotationManager? pointAnnotationManager;
    PointAnnotation? pointAnnotation;
    
    _onMapCreated(MapboxMap mapboxMap) async {
        this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
        mapboxMap.annotations.createPointAnnotationManager().then((value) async {
          pointAnnotationManager = value;
          _createMarker();
        });
      }

Future<void> _createMarker({double currentLat = 0, double currentLong = 0, }) async {
    final ByteData bytes =
    await rootBundle.load('assets/images/marker.png');
    final Uint8List list = bytes.buffer.asUint8List();

    pointAnnotationManager
        ?.create(PointAnnotationOptions(
        geometry: Point(
            coordinates: Position(
              currentLong == 0
                  ? widget.postLongitude != 0 ? widget.postLongitude : widget.location.longitude
                  : currentLong,
              currentLat == 0
                  ? widget.postLatitude != 0 ? widget.postLatitude : widget.location.latitude
                  : currentLat,
            )).toJson(),
        iconSize: 2.5,
        iconOffset: [0.0, -10.0],
        symbolSortKey: 10,
        image: list))
        .then((value) => pointAnnotation = value);
  }
```

The above is how to create the marker and place it at an arbitrary initial gps location. The below shows how to move the marker when you drag scroll on the map or when you click anywhere within the map:

```
Widget _map() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8, //mapbox needs to have a height
      child: MapWidget(
          resourceOptions: ResourceOptions(accessToken: MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN),
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        key: const ValueKey("mapWidget"),
        onScrollListener: (screenCoordinate) {
          pointAnnotationManager?.deleteAll();
          _createMarker(currentLat: screenCoordinate.x, currentLong: screenCoordinate.y);
        },
        onTapListener: (screenCoordinate) async {
          pointAnnotationManager?.deleteAll();
          _createMarker(currentLat: screenCoordinate.x, currentLong: screenCoordinate.y);
          setState(()  {});
        },
      )
    );
  }
```